# Как работает whoer.net?

Tags: http, tcp-ip

Приветствую, задался вопросом, а каким собственно образом, заходя на whoer.net  - он полностью выдает все о твоем браузере? Юзер агент, флеш, ип адреса и т.д

Какой то плагин за считывание информации? Хочу для саморазвития посмотреть код данного плагина/сервиса.

Comment: а почему вы уверены что там только JS? там и php есть.

Comment: Я не уверен, я спрашиваю :) Каким образом он все считывает? Обращается к системным файлам браузера? Считывает информацию с них ? Очень интересно, какой код за это отвечает

Comment: многое можно сделать руками, распечатав navigator и screen.

Comment: По подробнее?  Не понял

Answer (score 4):

Юзер-агент и операционную систему сам же браузер и отдаёт сайту. Причём, не только этому сайту, а вообще любому - это стандартная часть HTTP запроса, просто большинство других сайтов либо вообще ничего с этой информацией не делают, либо используют информацию об юзер-агенте только чтобы лучше подстроить под его особенности вёрстку.

С ip вообще всё тривиально, если бы запрос не содержал в себе ip отправителя, то сайт бы не знал, куда отправлять ответ. Поэтому наличие ip в запросе - это вообще основа самой возможности смотреть сайты.

По поводу флэша, js, activeX и тп, тоже всё просто - на странице сайта есть скрипты, использующие эти технологии, а сайт просто смотрит - отработали эти скрипты или нет. Если отработали, значит соответствующая технология в браузере включена.

Comment: IP-адрес это уже даже не HTTP, а TCP. В HTTP-запросе IP-адреса действительно нет.

Comment: @D-side, действительно, мой косяк. Сейчас поправлю ответ.

Comment: @D-side при чем тут вообще TCP? Вообще-то за него отвечает протокол IP :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov TCP/IP, ок :]

Comment: @D-side я тут метки переставил на вопросе, но не уверен на 100%. Можете проверить?

Comment: @NickVolynkin вполне годится. ТСу, правда, было невдомёк, что это связано с TCP/IP, но на практике ТС не всегда в курсе, какие темы затрагивает проблема :)

Comment: @D-side ок, спасибо. Да, есть «язык проблемы» и «язык решения». ))